# Creating WordPress Admin Themes

Tags: wp-admin

Is there any way to create our own admin theme rather than the default one.
or do we have to override the default style sheets to get the desired look??

Comment: What i can do is follow the steps in http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes#Creating_an_Admin_Theme_Plugin

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to add your own stylesheet, e.g.:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_style');
function custom_admin_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'adminStylesheet', plugins_url('adminstylesheet.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style('adminStylesheet');
}
```

You can then style the admin as you like. For UI changes beyond styling its not possible to answer within the scope of this question as there are too many things possible to say in an answer like this.

For an example of what's possible and some of the pitfalls and advantages of theming the admin area, see this article by Noel Tock:

http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/wp-admin-is-an-experience-too/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is generally recommended you don't customize the admin beyond basic css.

Reasons:

- Most of the admin functions do not have hooks that you can tie into.
- The admin UI changes during almost every release and majorly every few releases.
- It's to much work to make compatible.
- It's a good UI and people are used to it (also the dev team works hard on maintaining usability).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely can create your own admin themes. The [Executive Admin](http://l33t.me/executive-admin/) theme is a good example.

**Update:** I've just realised that this doesn't work with wordpress 3.3.1 (its designed for WP 3.2.1) - as the admin bar it uses at the top seems to conflict with the wordpress admin bar.